# Can't hide labels; JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

What am I doing wrong ? -*_*-

Alert displays, but that's it.

```
    <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderContent">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
            }
            else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)) {
            }
            else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
            }
            else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) {
            }
            else {
                alert("I'm a PC");
                $('#Label2').hide();
                $('#Label3').hide();
                $('#Label4').hide();
            }
       </script>

</asp:Content>

(...)

<div data-role="content">

            (...)

            <label id="Label1">
                Explanation to save it and/or bookmark (PC / Others)
            </label>
            <label id="Label2">
                Explanation to save it and/or bookmark (iOS)
            </label>
            <label id="Label3">
                Explanation to save it and/or bookmark (Android)
            </label>
            <label id="Label4">
                Explanation to save it and/or bookmark (BlackBerry)
            </label>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console? Has jQuery finished loading?

Comment: a minor detail, probably not the problem, but you are mis-using labels here.  labels are for identifying inputs.  you should use a span or div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about moving ur code below the html?

Or window.ready

Answer (score 2):

Could you try moving your javascript into the document ready event:

```
 $(function() {
      if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
        }
        else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)) {
        }
        else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
        }
        else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) {
        }
        else {
            alert("I'm a PC");
            $('#Label2').hide();
            $('#Label3').hide();
            $('#Label4').hide();
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you loaded the jquery library? Try this:

```
alert(jQuery);
```

It should come up true.

Comment: Yes, JQuery is loaded. It alerts true.

Comment: What about alert($('#Label2').length); ..? Does it alert 0 or 1?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is not loaded in your example.

Test it here, it works : http://jsfiddle.net/KCMAE/

Comment: It is. I put the code below the HTML like someone suggested and it worked.

Comment: That's what I mean't by 'not loaded'. It just wasn't clear enough I guess ;-) Should have added 'yet' in the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
$('#<%=Label2.ClientID %>').hide();
```